# Postgresql: How @GeneratedValue works in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.0, ebean, postgresql-9.3

I am very new to postgresql. *In playframework with Ebean*, I have used mysql and auto generated value there was actually auto incremented in that case. The sequence I got was 1,2,3,4...

But in Postgresql, the generated value doesn't seem to have such property. It seems that for every session it is starting with a number larger that the previous session's number and then auto incremented. The sequence in this case, 1,21,41,42,61,81,101,102,103...

My code segment:

```
@Entity
public class Post extends Model{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Required
    public int id;
```

I am using:

1. Playframework 2.3.4
2. Ebean
3. Postgres 9.3

I really don't know the reason. Is there any particular reason of such values? Is there any catch about this? Do I need to switch to auto increment? And if so, how do I do it?

Comment: What's the underlying JPA provider? Hibernate? EclipseLink? Something else? What queries is it actually running when you enable query logging? For PostgreSQL you want to convince the ORM to use a PostgreSQL sequence, but some of the Java ORMs are pretty frustrating about that.

Comment: Sorry for being late, I am using Ebean as ORM.

Answer (score 0):

K, so you're using AUTO strategy, as it's the default. I don't know much about Ebean, but with Hibernate, a sequence called hibernate_sequence is created.

This sequence would be shared by other entities, so that might be part of the reason for the gaps. Your ORM might also be pre-allocating sequence values for performance reasons.

Either way, I always use IDENTITY strategy with Postgres, even though Postgres doesn't use IDENTITY. It does however create a sequence per table, which is generally what you want.

Comment: The funny thing is if the sequence is being shared with other entities, I should get 2 to 20 as id for some other entities where I am getting sequence 1,21,41,42,61,81,101,102,103 for this for this entity, right? But I am not getting something like that. May be I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: @ShakibAhmed just use IDENTITY strategy and it should do what you want. It's probably pre-allocating ids as is, but you'd have to look at the source to be sure.